# Python regex find and replace inplace

Tags: python, regex

I have a snippet that finds floating point numbers like **1.321234123**. I would like to get rid of some precision and make **1.3212** out of it. But how can i access the found match, convert it and replace it?

**Python Source:**

```
import fileinput
import re

myfile = open("inputRegex.txt", "r")

for line in myfile:
    line = re.sub(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", "foundValue", line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

**The Input File:**

```
4.2abc -4.5 abc - 1.321234123 abc + .1e10 abc . abc 1.01e-2 abc

   1.01e-.2 abc 123 abc .123
```

Comment: Input file does not contain numbers like `1.321234123`.

Comment: good catch! i've changed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`fileinput.FileInput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput), with `inplace=True`. printed line will be used as a replacement string for each line.

```
myfile = fileinput.FileInput("inputRegex.txt", inplace=True)

for line in myfile:
    line = re.sub(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?",
                  "foundValue",
                  line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

---

**UPDATE**

`re.sub` can accept a function as replacement. It will be called with match object and the return value of the function is used as a replacement string.

The following is slightly modified version to use captured groups (to use in replacement function).

```
line = re.sub(r"([+-]? *)(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?",
              lambda m: m.group(1) + re.sub('(\..{4}).*', r'\1', m.group(2)) + (m.group(3) or ''),
              line.rstrip())
```

Comment: but "foundValue" is a placeholder, i want to represent the actual match und would like to edit it.

Comment: @user1767754, I updated the answer accordingly. Please check it out.

Comment: @user1767754, Do you want replace `1e-10` with `0.0000`, and `1e10` with `10000000000.0000` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import fileinput
import re

myfile = open("inputRegex.txt", "r")

def changePrecision(matchObj):
    return str(round(float(matchObj.group(0).replace(" ","")),4))

for line in myfile:
    newLine = re.sub(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", changePrecision, line)
    print newLine
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
num_decimal_places = 2
re.sub(r"(\d+)(\.\d{1,num_decimal_places})\d*", r"\1\2", line.rstrip())
```

`\1\2` captures the matches in the two sets of parentheses. This doesn't round, but it will truncate